# saving activity with shared preferences

Tags: android

making a respectable app which contains 3 activities.
the third on is a messenger, when I press back button and get back to the previous activity(the first one), everything that I just wrote in edittextes get cleaned (text, number),I want to use shared preferences, any help?``

```
package com.example.AzaaadCompany.mymessenger;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class thirdActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  EditText number;
  EditText msg;
  Button btnsend;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);

    number=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.noteText);
    msg=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editTextmsg);
    btnsend=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button);

    btnsend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        String mynumber = number.getText().toString();
        String mymsg = msg.getText().toString();
        if (mynumber.length() >10 ) {
          sendMessage(mynumber, mymsg);
        } else {

        }
      }
    });
  }

  private void sendMessage(String mynumber, String mymsg){
    try {
      SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
      smsManager.sendTextMessage(mynumber,null,mymsg,null,null);
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e){
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"something is wrong",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the shared preferences

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
  "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Writing data to SharedPreferences

```
 // Writing data to SharedPreferences
 Editor editor = prefs.edit();
 editor.putString("key", "some value"); // replace 'some value' with your edit text value
 editor.putInt("your_int_key", yourIntValue);
 editor.commit();
```

Reading data from SharedPreferences

```
 // Reading from SharedPreferences
 String value = prefs.getString("key", ""); // replace empty string with some default string (useful if key not found)
 int intValue = prefs.getInt("your_int_key", -1);
```

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Write

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
editor.commit();
```

Read

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_high_score_default);
long highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), defaultValue);
```

from:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for every 3 answers ,
however your answers had imperfections.I incorporated your answers with my knowledge and that's the result.

@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String name = msg.getText().toString();
    String name2 = number.getText().toString();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("MATN",name);
    editor.putString("MATN2",name2);
    editor.commit();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String value = preferences.getString("MATN2", "");
    String matn = preferences.getString("MATN","Hello"):                                   


    msg=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editTextmsg);
    number=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.numberText);
    msg.setText(matn);
    number.setText(value);

    super.onResume();
}
```

}